# Make a list in VB Excel based on cells in the same row

Tags: excel, list

I have a worksheet with names and addresses of people. I want to make a Userform that finds a person in Column 1 and then output the data from the following cells in the same row as a list. So the output would look like this:

> John
>
> Time Squares 12
>
> New York
>
> 0123123123

I manage to find the cell and output the information, but I can't find a way to find and add the info in the following cells in the same row.

```
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = txtSearch
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("servicepartner").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            
                MailFormat.Text = Rng.Value & vbNewLine
                
            
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You should look at `Rng.Offset` property. Is it `MailFormat.Text = Rng.Value & vbNewLine` you want to modify?

Comment: I solved this by setting up a variable (StringRow) with the rownumber of the search result. Then output Cells( StringRow, "B").Value & vbNewLinge & Cells( StringRow, "C") $ etc. etc. Works fine!

Comment: I have posted my code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting up a variable (StringRow) with the rownumber of the search result. Then output Cells( StringRow, "B").Value & vbNewLinge & Cells( StringRow, "C") $ etc. etc. Works fine!

The code now looks like this:

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range

'This variable will find the Row number
Dim StringRow As Long


    FindString = txtSearch
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("servicepartner").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)


        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

    'Output Results (i shorted this to not give you a headache)
            StringRow = Rng.Row
            MailFormatKlant.Text =  Rng.Value & vbNewLine & _
            Sheets("servicepartner").Cells(StringRow, "B").Value & _
            vbNewLine & Sheets("servicepartner").Cells(StringRow, "D").Value & _
            " te " & Sheets("servicepartner").Cells(StringRow, "C").Value & _
            vbNewLine & Sheets("servicepartner").Cells(StringRow, "F").Value & _
            vbNewLine & Sheets("servicepartner").Cells(StringRow, "G").Value & _


        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If


    End With
End If
```

I hope someone finds this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was suggesting.

```
        MailFormatKlant.Text =  Rng.Value & _
        vbNewLine & Rng.Offset(0,1).Value & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & Rng.Offset(0,3).Value & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & " te " & Rng.Offset(0,2).Value & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & Rng.Offset(0,5).Value & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & Rng.Offset(0,6).Value
```